# Как найти (и удалить) файлы по содержимому во всех вложеных папках в windows через терминал?

Tags: windows, консоль, windows-10

Выполняю поиск в терминале *windows10* по названию файла в папке и вложеных подпапках:
`C:\Users\user1>dir settings.xml /s`.
Файл(ы) находит, но не знаю как добавить параметр поиска по содержимому и как удалить их, т.к. файлов может быть много и раскиданы по подпапкам.
Другой вариант:
`C:\Users\user1>find "login" settings.xml`
тут ищет по тексту, но не ищет во вложеных папках, и тоже не знаю как удалить.

Вообще, обе команды мне нужны как альтернативы линуксовым:

```
grep -lrnw ~/.m2 -e '\u0000' | xargs rm
find ~/.m2/ -name resolver-status.properties -delete
```

Comment: Используйте расширенный вариант утилиты поиска строк `findstr /?`

Comment: А как удалить найденные в таком случае?

Comment: С использованием парсера `for`, который будет передавать найденное имя как переменную. в команду `del`. Типа: `FOR /F "DELIMS=/" %i IN ('FINDSTR /S /M "login" c:\User\User1\settings.xml') DO @ECHO DEL /Q/F %i`